# Find constants A, B and C using a nonlinear regression (e.g. LeastSquares)

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have an  asymptotic behavior of $\beta$ with respect to $f$ that is described by a curve:

$\frac{\beta}{f}=A+B+f^C$

If I have the following pairs of $(f,\beta)$:

```
data={{0.1, 0.21}, {0.2, 0.44}, {0.3, 0.69}, {0.4, 0.96}, {0.5, 
  1.25}, {0.6, 1.56}, {0.7, 1.89}, {0.8, 2.24}, {0.9, 2.61}, {1., 3.}};
```

How can I find the constants $A$,$B$ and $C$ using a nonlinear regression?

Comment: Having A+B in the right hand side doesn't make all that much sense since the best you will ever be able to do is to identify their sum.

Comment: Multiply both side of your equation by $f$ and use `NonlinearModelFit` and follow @bills advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First separate the problem into dependent and independent variables:
$\beta$=$f(A+B+f^C)$

Then use:

```
nlmf=NonlinearModelFit[data, f (a + b + f^c), {a,b,c}, {f}];
```

This will generate the nonlinear model fit and store it in nlmf. You can extract values at given $f$ by using:

```
nlmf[0.7] (* for f == 0.7 *)
```

Or you can extract the parameters by doing:

```
nlmf["BestFitParameters"]
```

Note 1: As pointed out in several comments, it is impossible in this model to determine $A$ and $B$ individually, so there's little point to trying to fit both.

```
nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[data, f (ab + f^c), {ab,c}, {f}];
```

This could be used to find their sum, but you'll need another condition to find either individually.

Comment: You need to deal with the issue that @bills pointed out:  you can't estimate both $A$ and $B$.  You can only estimate their sum.  Look at `nlmf["CorrelationMatrix"]` to see that this is a problem.

Comment: This is true, but that's actually an aside to fitting the function with the model, it's just that the model is ambiguously defined. You can't uniquely determine $A$ or $B$, but `NonlinearModelFit` still found values for them that worked. That probably can't be guaranteed in most cases, but it works for this.

Comment: The sensible thing to do is to rename A and B as D, and then estimate D. (Hint: It will be the sum of A and B.)

Comment: I already added that to the answer as a note, although as `ab` rather than `d`. That being said, `NonlinearModelFit` works fine even if they're not combined, it's just that the problem is ill-formed.

Comment: "but `NonlinearModelFit` still found values for them that worked."  And with no warnings.  Shouldn't that be scary?  Yes, the predictions are not affected.  However, I can certainly image folks "interpreting" the resulting coefficients as meaningful - especially without any warning.  One could hope that suspicions would be raised when one looked at the resulting estimates from above: `{a -> 1., b -> 1., c -> 1.}`.

Comment: I definitely agree that it is scary that it throws no warnings, but in my opinion the onus of determining whether a model is correct, appropriate, or well-defined is generally on the user, not on `NonlinearModelFit`. That said, it could definitely do more in this situation to let the user know that something fishy is going on, if it can detect that to begin with.